# How to pronounce several consecutive '“三声” characters?

Tags: pronunciation, tones

It is known that the first character in a two-"三声"-character word is prounounced as "二声"。For example,

勇敢 （ㄩㄥ**ˇ**　ㄍㄢˇ）is usually pronounced as "（ㄩㄥ**ˊ**　ㄍㄢˇ）".

How about when in a sentence there are some consecutative "三声" characters?

Say the following sentence:

请你给李雪主讲讲勇敢的打死老虎者。

How to pronounce the tones?

Answer (score 1):

I thought about such questions before as well, it turns out in this case, you would just pronounce the way it flows better for you, for example

> qíng nǐ géi lǐ xué zhǔ jiáng jiǎng yóng gǎn dē dá sǐ láo hú zhě
>
> qǐng ní gěi (pause) lǐ xué zhǔ jiáng jiǎng yóng gǎn dē dá sǐ láo hú zhě

You can imagine you are trying to speak out a number whose value is

> 3.55555555555555555555555...

You would naturally alternate second and third tone.

Comment: Thanks! In 3.555555555555, is 点 三声 or 二声?

Comment: @Zuriel It would be more natural to me if it is third tone.